# JMeter - Error when starting test plan- keytool error: proxysever.jks (access is denied)

Tags: jmeter

I am following JMeter User guide to start recording my first test plan. When I click the Start button in HTTP Test Script Recorder, I got this error:

> Could not create script recorder – see log for details  >> keytool error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: proxyserver.jks (Access is denied)

How could I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. pls share the reference URL for JMeter user Guide 2. JMeter version 3. screenshot of the test plan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Background: JMeter creates a self-signed SSL certificate in order to be able to decrypt and record HTTPS requests, this `proxyserver.jks` is a [Java Keystore](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores) which is being generated by JMeter in its "bin" folder when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- Explanation: The error you are getting most probably indicates that you don't have permissions to write anything into the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
- Workarounds:

  1. You can try launching JMeter with elevated rights (run as administrator or superuser or whoever having write access to JMeter's "bin" folder
  2. You can change the location where JMeter tries to generate this `proxyserver.jks` file by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

     ```
     proxy.cert.directory=/path/to/folder/where/you/have/write/access
     ```

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

     Another option is passing the property value via [`-J` command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like

     ```
     jmeter -Jproxy.cert.directory=/path/to/folder/where/you/have/write/access -n -t ....
     ```

  Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information regarding JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that worked for me was to start JMeter.bat from bin folder from cmd which was "run as administrator". After this, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I was using jmeter v5.5 and was facing similar issue . I upgraded my jmeter app with latest v5.6 and extract the folder into desktop itself . After retrying to record it worked .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34678291)